# Insertion Sort For Singly Linked List Java

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list, insertion-sort

I'm trying to make an Insertion Sort for a Linked List class to sort in ascending. I'm not really sure what I need to do. I can't find a way to go back to the beginning of the list.

```
public static void LLInsertionSort (LinkedList LL){

    IntNode currentNode = head;
    IntNode tail = null;
    while(currentNode != null&& tail != head ){


         while (currentNode.getData() > currentNode.getNext().getData()){

             int temp = currentNode.getData();
             currentNode.setData(currentNode.getNext().getData());
             currentNode.getNext().setData(temp);
```

Comment: *Sigh* I'm sure one of these days it would actually be something related to JavaScript but...I guess we should say the same thing as we say to Death - not today.

Comment: Your code is incomplete.  Also, you have a variable `head`, though where it comes from is unclear, why can't you use that?  Also, why are you swapping node `data` rather than re-organizing nodes?

Answer (score 0):

You need to start each time from the **first Node in your list**.

```
public static IntList LLInsertionSort(Node head)
{
   IntNode current = head;
   IntNode tail = null;
   while(current != null&& tail != head )
   {
      IntNode next = current;
      for( ; next.next != tail;  next = next.next)
      {
        if(next.value <= next.next.value)
        {
          int temp = next.value;
          next.value = next.next.value;
          next.next.value = temp;
        }
      }
      tail = next;
      current = head;
   }
   return this;
}
```